# flex core ByteArray Image

Tags: arrays, image, apache-flex

```
                var myFile:File = new File("./test.jpg");
                var myFileStream1:FileStream = new FileStream();
                myFileStream1.open(myFile, FileMode.READ);
                                    var byte:ByteArray = new ByteArray();  
                                myFileStream1.readBytes(byte,0,byte.bytesAvailable);
                myFileStream1.close();
```

now how can i add byte variable to the canvas ? for example 
var canvas:Canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.addChild(byte);
is it possible to add ByteArray to the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I sloved this without Image control I used decoder concept.Here is the below:
It worked.

```
loader.loadBytes(eizo.idolImage);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    function (e:Event):void {
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loader.width, loader.height);
    bmpData.draw(loader);
    var ui:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    ui.addChild(new Bitmap(bmpData));
    canvas0.addChild(ui);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. It is because `ByteArray` itself cannot be displayed since the Flash Player do not know what it is.

In your case you are going to display the "test.jpg" image on a `Canvas`, right? You may simply set `Image` control's `source` property to the loaded `ByteArray` object and add it to the `Canvas`. See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Image.html

Comment: Well, your (msaif) solution definitely will do the job. But it actually IS what will be done in `Image` control internally. If you are using Flex framework, why avoid using `Image` control when its code is shorter comparing to using `Loader` + `BitmapData` + `Bitmap` + `UIComponent`?